# Community Head Markup script not available in afterRender code

Tags: community, lightning-renderer

I have added an Adobe DTM script to the Head Markup of my community, and added the trusted site CSP details etc. I'm then attempting to create the data layer JSON object in an afterRender of a component (all working fine), but then calling the _satellite.track() method from the external Adobe DTM script is failing and a console.log directly after it is never reached but the line before is.

e.g.
console.log("here");
_satellite.track("Virtual Page View");
console.log("now here");

the console shows 'here' only.

Once the page loads fully, I can then manually enter _satellite.track("stuff") into the console and it works fine, but it appears that the Head Markup isn't loaded in time for the afterRender.

Does anyone have any idea how this can be resolved?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else experiencing this. It's a simple matter of Lightning Locker blocking the Head Markup script code. I moved the script out of the header and created a new component to sit in the community footer. That script simply generated a script tag, and then called the track method once it was loaded. All now working.